# Magento custom module admin url returns to frontend and 404 error page

Tags: php, magento

I am getting 404 error page in my custom module admin url.

My admin end url like 
magento1.9/index.php/admin/fortuneform/index/key/43a83958a538fd0a628c3236d4d059f7/

Once I am click this url it goes to frontend with same url and shows 404 error page.

config.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Fortunesoft_Fortuneform>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Fortunesoft_Fortuneform>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <fortuneform>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Fortunesoft_Fortuneform</module>
                    <frontName>fortuneform</frontName>
                </args>
            </fortuneform>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <fortuneform>
                    <file>fortuneform.xml</file>
                </fortuneform>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
    <routers>
        <fortuneform>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <fortuneform before="Mage_Adminhtml">Fortunesoft_Fortuneform_Adminhtml</fortuneform>
                </modules>                  
            </args>
        </fortuneform>
    </routers>
</admin>
<global>
        <models>
            <fortuneform>
                <class>Fortunesoft_Fortuneform_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>fortuneform_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </fortuneform>
            <fortuneform_mysql4>
                <class>Fortunesoft_Fortuneform_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <fortuneform>
                        <table>fortuneform</table>
                    </fortuneform>
                </entities>
            </fortuneform_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <fortuneform_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Fortunesoft_Fortuneform</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </fortuneform_setup>
            <fortuneform_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>    
            </fortuneform_write>
            <fortuneform_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </fortuneform_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <fortuneform>
                <class>Fortunesoft_Fortuneform_Block</class>
            </fortuneform>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <fortuneform>
                <class>Fortunesoft_Fortuneform_Helper</class>
            </fortuneform>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

adminhtml.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu><fortuneform module="fortuneform">
            <title>Fortuneform</title>
            <sort_order>71</sort_order>
            <children>
                <items module="fortuneform">
                    <title>Manage Items</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                  <action>adminhtml/fortuneform</action>
                </items>
            </children>
        </fortuneform></menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <fortuneform>
                        <title>Fortuneform Module</title>
                        <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                    </fortuneform>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>   
    </acl>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <fortuneform>
                <file>fortuneform.xml</file>
            </fortuneform>
        </updates>
    </layout>
```

adminhtml/default/default/layout/fortuneform.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <layout version="0.1.0">
    <fortuneform_adminhtml_fortuneform_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="fortuneform/adminhtml_fortuneform" name="fortuneform" />
        </reference>
    </fortuneform_adminhtml_fortuneform_index>
 </layout>
```

Controllers/Adminhtml/FortuneformController.php file :

```
class Fortunesoft_Fortuneform_Adminhtml_FortuneformController extends  Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    protected function _initAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('fortuneform/items')
            ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Items Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'));
        return $this;
    }   

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->_initAction();       
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('fortuneform/adminhtml_fortuneform'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    } }
```

Please help me....

Comment: please use magento1.9/admin/index.php/fortuneform/index/

Comment: I am developing module based on [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table) this tutorial. It not have any <frontName>

Comment: You have create app/etc/modules/Fortunesoft_Fortuneform.xml ?

Comment: First please check your module will be show in admin or not. system>confirgration>Advanced>Advanced by this name Fortunesoft_Fortuneform

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Fortunesoft_Fortuneform>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Fortunesoft_Fortuneform>
    </modules>
</config>

Comment: create file Fortunesoft_Fortuneform.xml on that name and past above code or place file on that location app/etc/modules/Fortunesoft_Fortuneform.xml then check in admin on above location path or check above url it's working i think.

Comment: Yes, already I have created the xml file, front end working fine, admin only has the error. If I am inserted any value directly into the table means I am getting the output in my front end

Comment: okay let me check again.

Comment: Where is your controller `Controllers/Adminhtml/FortuneformController.php` (uppercase 'C' or lowercase 'c')? It should be lowercase 'Fortunesoft/controllers/Adminhtml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **adminhtml.xml** should look like this. It has action defined as

```
<action>adminhtml/fortuneform</action>
```

but it should be `<action>fortuneform/adminhtml_fortuneform</action>`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>

    <menu>
    <fortuneform module="fortuneform">
            <title>Fortuneform</title>
            <sort_order>71</sort_order>
            <children>
                <items module="fortuneform">
                    <title>Manage Items</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                  <action>fortuneform/adminhtml_fortuneform</action> 
                </items>
            </children>
        </fortuneform>
    </menu>

    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <fortuneform>
                        <title>Fortuneform Module</title>
                        <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                    </fortuneform>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>   
    </acl>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <fortuneform>
                <file>fortuneform.xml</file>
            </fortuneform>
        </updates>
    </layout>

</config>
```

Replace config.xml with below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Fortunesoft_Fortuneform>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Fortunesoft_Fortuneform>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <fortuneform>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Fortunesoft_Fortuneform</module>
                    <frontName>fortuneform</frontName>
                </args>
            </fortuneform>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <fortuneform>
                    <file>fortuneform.xml</file>
                </fortuneform>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>


        <admin>
        <routers>
            <fortuneform>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
            <fortuneform before="Mage_Adminhtml">Fortunesoft_Fortuneform_Adminhtml</fortuneform>
                    <frontName>fortuneform</frontName>
                </args>
            </fortuneform>
        </routers>
    </admin>


<global>
        <models>
            <fortuneform>
                <class>Fortunesoft_Fortuneform_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>fortuneform_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </fortuneform>
            <fortuneform_mysql4>
                <class>Fortunesoft_Fortuneform_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <fortuneform>
                        <table>fortuneform</table>
                    </fortuneform>
                </entities>
            </fortuneform_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <fortuneform_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Fortunesoft_Fortuneform</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </fortuneform_setup>
            <fortuneform_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>    
            </fortuneform_write>
            <fortuneform_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </fortuneform_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <fortuneform>
                <class>Fortunesoft_Fortuneform_Block</class>
            </fortuneform>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <fortuneform>
                <class>Fortunesoft_Fortuneform_Helper</class>
            </fortuneform>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Also your controller folder name should be **controller** i.e. in lower case

Clear your cache and try

Comment: Deleted cache folder, cleared admin cache, flush cache storage and cleared my browser history and cache... but still no luck :-(

Comment: Yes you are correct, when I change Contollers to controllers its working. But I am getting a blank page in my admin end. ie) Header and footer okay, but the content section am getting blank/empty.

Comment: You can change your adminhtml.xml and config.xml as posted above and that should be good to go.

Comment: I tried everything, my link look likes index.php/fortuneform/adminhtml_fortuneform/index/key/dfa53582fc64ac52bd084130a5fd4ee8/ but its showing blank in the content area, is I need to change any other file?

Comment: In your indexAction, echo-exit. If the function is called, you are on right path.

Comment: Yes, if I am echo means its showing top of the page in admin end, and put exit in the end means only the echo text showing in the page. So i think am going into the right way :-)

Answer (score 0):

You controller path should be

> controllers/Adminhtml/FortuneformController.php (lowercase c in controllers)

Not

> Controllers/Adminhtml/FortuneformController.php